# My IE9 is fine with trailing comma, user's IE9 is not; why?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a web app with a JavaScript file using code like the following:

```
var foo = {a:'b',c:'d',e:'f',};
```

On my computer, IE9 (9.0.8112.16421) works correctly; the JavaScript is parsed and executed as on Chrome/FF/Safari. Another user claims to have the same version of IE, yet gets this error in the Developer Tools Console:

```
SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number 
blob.js?modified=1304026278, line 524 character 136
```

*Column 136 is the trailing comma/closing brace for the object literal.*

I've 'fixed' the code so the user should have no more problems, but I'm wondering:
What could make the same version of IE on two different computers treat the JavaScript differently?

Comment: as a sidenote, when you place a trailing commar in an array e.g. a,b,c, this array contains 4 not 3 items, the 4th being 'undefined'. Another reason to avoid trailing commars. ( some browsers would say there are 3 and assume the trailing comma is human error )

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One of the reasons may be that user has pressed the "Compatibility View" button. The trailing comma causes syntax error in IE7 document mode.

Comment: 'Compatibility View' is a horrible abomination that should not exist.

Comment: It looks like Document Mode also has some effect on whether or not this error occurs. In Browser Mode of IE9 Compat View and Document Mode of IE9 Standards, I don't get the error, but if I set Document Mode to Quirks or IE7 Standards I get the error.

Comment: Thanks; I had no idea that the document mode would affect JS behavior in any way, let alone the parsing!

Answer (score -4):

Its most likely due to a browser setting suppressing the error on your browser.

Comment: No, I have the Developer Tools console open and no such error appears; further, the functionality of the page is correct on my machine, while the user's machine fails to execute the JavaScript in the file.

Comment: It could be this. Check Tools->Internet Options->Advanced. Under Browsing, make sure that "Display a notification about every script error" is checked, also make sure that disable script debugging is unchecked (both versions)

Comment: @Tom I didn't downvote you, but I don't think the error message is suppressed because @Phrogz wrote that "JavaScript is parsed and executed".

Comment: @Tom duri is correct; I downvoted because I (thought I) made it clear that there is a functional difference between the two computers, not just hiding the error.

Comment: Thats fair enough. Some explanation would have been nice though.